# Problems with calling functions in other file (Firebase Functions)

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm making an API using express in Firebas Functions. So Im having the following problem:

error:`Error>>TypeError: firebase_util.updateWalletData is not a function`

Basically I have a index.js, and two files (firebase and axies.js)

The problem comes in a function in axies.js:

```
async function firstUpdate(wallet) {
const baseUrl = 'https://game-api.skymavis.com/game-api/clients/'
const path = '/items/1'

try {
    
    let newAdd = wallet.replace('ronin:', '0x');
    let requestURL = baseUrl+newAdd + path;
    console.log('wallet>>' + newAdd);

    let response = await axios.get(requestURL, {raxConfig: {statusCodesToRetry: [[100, 199], [400, 429], [500, 599]]}});

    if(response.status === 200) {

        let requestData = response['data'];
        console.log('data>>' + util.inspect(requestData, true, null, true));
        console.log('request>>' + requestURL);

        let total_slp = requestData.total;
        let last_claim_amount = 0;
        let claim_timestamp = 0;

        if (requestData.blockchain_related.signature) {
            last_claim_amount = requestData.blockchain_related.signature.amount;
            claim_timestamp = requestData.blockchain_related.signature.timestamp;
        } else {
            claim_timestamp = requestData.item.created_at;
        }

        let next_claim_timestamp = claim_timestamp + 1296000;
        let ronin_slp = requestData.blockchain_related.balance;
        console.log('ron>>' + ronin_slp);

        if (ronin_slp === null) {
            ronin_slp = 0;
            console.log('ronin value changed to>>' + ronin_slp);
        }

        let ingame_slp = total_slp - ronin_slp;
        let lastupdate = Math.floor(+new Date() / 1000);

        let walletInfo = {total_slp, last_claim_amount, claim_timestamp, next_claim_timestamp, ronin_slp, ingame_slp, lastupdate};
        console.log('util>>' + util.inspect(walletInfo, true, null, true));
        firebase_util.updateWalletData(wallet, walletInfo);
    }
} catch(error) {
    console.log('Error>>' + error);
}
```

}

I have a cronjob that once an hour update the information in all wallets, but this function is called when a new wallet is added, so it force an update to get the data for the first time.

In the firebase.js Im doing all the job from writing/reading all the data in firebase realtime database.

firebase.js:

```
async function updateWalletData(walletID, walletData) {
database.ref('ScolarsToCheck/' + walletID + '/walletData/').update(walletData);
return {'message': 'updated', 'status': 200};
```

}

```
module.exports = {setCalendar, createEmptyCalendar, checkCalendar, getAllScolars, addScolar, deleteScolar, addExpenses, deleteExpenses, addClaim, deleteClaim, getScolars, updateWalletData};
```

All the other stuff works great, but the calls to firebase_util.updateWalletData() just stopped working. I have a lot of functions and endpoints in index.js calling to those functions and all works smothly, except for that single call.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up.

Comment: Can you show the import statement which you are using to import that function ?

Comment: @Dharmaraj Im using const firebase_util = require('./firebase') to import all the functions there. The 3 files are in the same directory.

Comment: I'm not sure what's causing the issue but please add `await` before `database.ref()...` in that function. Because update method returns a promise and in the main file as well `await firebase_util.updateWalletData(wallet, walletInfo);`

Comment: @Dharmaraj u are right, done. However that doesn't fix the problem. I just started to check endpoint by endpoint and it's really weird, cause when I call functions in firebase.js from index.js, it works good. However, any call I make from functions in firebase.js from axies.js just don't work, so probably the problem is in axies.js but I can't see any difference